# PHP CASE statement not working with ZERO values

Tags: php, switch-statement

I don't understand what's happening here. Logically, it doesn't make any sense to me.

```
<?php
$level = 0;

switch ($level) {

  case $level > 80: $answer = 'high'; break;
  case $level > 60: $answer = 'moderate-to-high'; break;
  case $level > 40: $answer = 'moderate'; break;
  case $level > 20: $answer = 'low-to-moderate'; break;
  default: $answer = 'low'; break;
}   
echo $answer;
?>
```

When $level == 0, it returns "high". This doesn't make any sense to me. Can someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change `switch ($level)` to `switch (true)` and this will work.

[`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements perform equality tests on the values in the cases. PHP is evaluating your `>` comparisons, so `case $level > 80` becomes `case false`. `false` is considered to be equal to `0`, so the first case matches.

Comment: This makes so much sense to me now. I had a fundamental misunderstanding in the way switch works. Thanks for the education!

Comment: @pbamey, yup, good answer, I agree, so accept it and give Phil his due.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be the recommended approach of using a switch statement though, I wouldn't say it reads very well.

Answer (score 5):

The quantity after the `case` needs to be just the value, not a boolean expression.  I'm guessing that PHP is evaluating `case $level > 80` as `case ($level > 80)` which is becoming `case 0` (i.e., false, since `$level` is indeed NOT less than 80) and so you're matching the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can do this in php?

I just checked the [manual of switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and you have to provide a distinct value.

I think if you can write it again into something like:

```
$levelDivTwenty = intval($level/20);
$levelDivTwenty = ($levelDivTwenty>4)?4:$levelDivTwenty;
```

and then case on that.

```
switch ($levelDivTwenty) {
  case 4: //same as $level > 80 before...
  case 3: //>60 etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out you can't use *switch* like that, but how about defining it like this:

```
<?
$level = 21;
$answers = array('low', 'low-to-moderate',
                 'moderate', 'moderate-to-high', 'high');

echo $answers[intval(($level-1)/20)];
?>
```

---

***Note***: If **$level = 0**, then expression inside **intval()** will be **-1/20**, **which is less then -1 and therefore will be rounded to 0**.

Comment: that's an interesting approach

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really how switch is intended to be used.  It's to evaluate for a specific value.

Use an If/else if here, instead of complicating your life to make a switch work like one.