# Range in PHPs switch

Tags: php, switch-statement, range

My teacher gave me this task.

> Make an *int* variable that indicates day of the week *(1-7)*. Make a switch statement with following cases:
>
> - 1-5 `echo "Weekday";`
> - 6-7 `echo "Weekend";`
> - Other values `echo "Unknown day";`

My problem is zero.

At first I wrote this code.

```
$day = 7;

switch ($day) {
    case $day >= 1 && $day <= 5:
        echo "Weekday";
        break;

    case $day >= 6 && $day <= 7:
        echo "Weekend";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown day";
        break;
}
```

It works works with every number except 0. When `$day = 0;` it is choosing first case and says it's a *Weekday*.

I've also tried this.

```
$day = 7;

switch ($day) {
    case 1-5:
        echo "Weekday";
        break;

    case 6-7:
        echo "Weekend";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown day";
        break;
}
```

But it's even worse. I always get the `default` option.

I know there are better ways to do this, but I need to do it only with a switch statement.

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php but I think you can add to your first code where you did $day >= , right before `default:` add just `case 0` and don't add break

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800798/php-case-statement-not-working-with-zero-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that your switch statement is comparing the switch value with the expression in each case statement:

if `$day = 0` and `case $day >= 1 && $day <= 5:` then `$day >= 1 && $day <= 5` is false and `$day` (from the switch value) loose-type compares to false, so this expression evaluates as true.... and is executed.

switch/case is not a glorified series of if/elseif/else statements..... its a comparison between the defined switch value and the case statement

**EDIT**

As for your second attempt:

`case 1-5` is `1` minus `5` = `-4`:

Answer (score 2):

You can stack the case statements that have values that belong together. Here is a snippet:

```
case 6:
case 7:
    echo "Weekend";
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although for this I would use if which would be better in switch false nulll will be equal to 0 also it's hard to compare with 1 because it's not strict it's called [loose comprasion](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

Code with switch:

```
<?php

$day = 0;

switch ($day) {
    case 1: // if you put as day anything but 0, false, null it will go to true
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
      echo 'weekday';
      break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
      echo 'weekend';
      break;
    default:
      echo 'unknown';  
}
```

Ask @Mark Baker wrote switch compares ($day) with every case value so you compared result of an expression conditions looked like:

```
 if ($day == 1-5) // 0 == -4 
 elseif ($day == 6-7) // 0 == -1
 else
```

It could work if you did `switch(true)` but it makes no much sense, code below:

```
<?php

$day = 7;

switch (true) { 
    case $day > 0 && $day < 6: 
      echo 'weekday';
      break;
    case $day === 6 || $day === 7 :
      echo 'weekend';
      break;
    default:
      echo 'unknown';
}
```