# Switch return wrong value

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a switch statement to show a grade based on the points students get.

students with points >= 80 get A
students with points >=70 get B
students with points >= 50 get C
students with points >= 30 get D
students with points >= 0 get E

The problem is when the point is 0, it returns A instead of E. Here is the `switch` statement.

```
$point = 0;
switch ($point) {
        case $point >= 80:
            echo 'A';
            break;
        case $point >= 70:
            echo 'B';
            break;
        case $point >= 50:
            return 'C';
            break;
        case $point >= 30:
            echo 'D';
            break;
        case $point >= 0:
            echo 'E';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'F';
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CASE statement not working with ZERO values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800798/php-case-statement-not-working-with-zero-values)

Comment: if you `var_dump($point >= 80)` its `false` and `false` is considered `0` so first case is matched irrespective to logical condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to compare `$point` to a boolean value (like `$point >= 80`). It is matching the first case because `$point = 0` is false and `$point >= 80` is false too, so it is matching the first case and echoing `A`. If you want to use a comparison on the cases you have to use the following code:

```
$point = 0;

switch (true) {
    case $point >= 80:
        echo 'A';
        break;
    case $point >= 70:
        echo 'B';
        break;
    case $point >= 50:
        echo 'C';
        break;
    case $point >= 30:
        echo 'D';
        break;
    case $point >= 0:
        echo 'E';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'F';
        break;
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/lyBUmA

**Another solution using `if` and `elseif` instead of `switch`:**

```
$point = 0;

if ($point >= 80) {
    echo 'A';
} elseif ($point >= 70) {
    echo 'B';
} elseif ($point >= 50) {
    echo 'C';
} elseif ($point >= 30) {
    echo 'D';
} elseif ($point >= 0) {
    echo 'E';
} else {
    echo 'F';
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/FRlorS

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, you try to use boolean condition. Use if else instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

yes obviously this question is duplicate. instead of using

> switch ($point)

you should use

> switch (true)

and it works i checked

```
<?php
$point = 0;
switch (true) {
    case $point >= 80:
        echo 'A';
        break;
    case $point >= 70:
        echo 'B';
        break;
    case $point >= 50:
        return 'C';
        break;
    case $point >= 30:
        echo 'D';
        break;
    case $point >= 0:
        echo 'E';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'F';
        break;
}
```

for more details please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800798/php-case-statement-not-working-with-zero-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 comparisons in case like :

```
case $point >= 80:
   echo 'A';
   break;
case ($point < 80 && $point >= 70):
   echo 'B';
   break;
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Switch/Case does not support >... Try if/elseif....

```
$point = 0;


if ($point >= 80)
    echo 'A';
elseif ($point >= 70)
    echo 'B';
elseif ($point >= 50)
    echo 'C';
elseif ($point >= 30)
    echo 'D';
elseif ($point >= 0)
    echo 'E';
else
    echo 'F';
```

Comment: Also note that your original has an odd bug in the middle where it says "return 'C'" instead of "echo 'C'".